# Encrypt in strophejs?

Tags: encryption, xmpp

XMPP allows to encrypt the message and BOSH has the key sequence mechanism. How to encrypt the message and use the key sequence mechanism in strophejs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm answering the question you wanted to ask, since it's not terribly clear.

When using BOSH, the preferred mechanism for channel security is to just use an HTTPS URL for all of your BOSH requests.  This encrypts all of the traffic from the client to server, including the rids/sids/etc.